# How to hookup jQuery autocomplete with POST query to remote data source?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to hook up a text field to jQuery UI's autocomplete with a remote data source using a POST query. So far I have this:

```
$( "#booking_student" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, respond ) {
                $.post( "/path/to/my/api.php", { student: request.term },
                        function( response ) {
                            //do something
                        } );
            }
        });
```

Using Firebug I can see that my API is returning the results I'd expect, but the autocomplete dropdown doesn't appear. What do I need to do to plug my results into the autocomplete dropdown? Do I need to populate a variable in the //do something section with the JSON results or?

Answer (score 10):

You need to supply the results to the `respond` callback that the widget is giving you:

```
$( "#booking_student" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, respond ) {
        $.post( "/path/to/my/api.php", { student: request.term },
            function( response ) {
                respond(response);
        });
    }
});
```

This of course assumes that your data is an array with items containing either a `label` property, a `value` property, or both. This is outlined in the [documentation for the `source` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Comment: Good answer, may want to note that it can be beneficial to add a datatype to `$.post()` as the fourth argument. Simply adding `, "json"` to the end can be needed sometimes